# Can I use Hadoop SequenceFile for deduplication?

Tags: hadoop, sequencefile

The Hadoop SequenceFile is basically a collection of key/value pairs. In my application, I need to consume events from Kafka and handle the possible duplicates. Can I use SequenceFile for deduplication? That is, in the Kafka consumer, I would consume Kafka message, and store each ConsumerRecord in a local SequenceFile (without Hadoop). This way, the duplicates will be removed in the SequenceFile, and I can send this file to HDFS for further processing later.

Comment: I think you want a MapFile, https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/MapFile.html  But, no, duplicate keys are preventable within it

Comment: You could use Kafka Streams to de-dupe records (maybe Spark, haven't tried it). Or use a compacted Kafka topic